# Get the first date of the first five-consecutive dates in a list using R

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
structure(list(V1 = c("1979-01-28", "1979-01-29", "1979-01-30", 
"1979-02-13", "1979-02-14", "1979-02-17", "1979-02-18", "1979-02-19", 
"1979-02-20", "1979-02-21", "1979-02-22", "1979-02-23", "1979-03-07", 
"1979-03-14", "1979-03-18", "1979-03-29", "1979-03-30", "1979-03-31",
"1979-04-01", "1979-04-02", "1979-04-03", "1979-04-04", "1979-04-05")), class = 
"data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-22L))
```

This is a list of dates. The interval is daily but with gaps.

I would like to get the first date of a five-day sequence that occurred first.

So in the example above, the expected output is "1979-02-17".

Right now, I am getting the dates manually. How can I do this in R?

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Comment: omg..my mistake..ill correct this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `rle` and `diff`.

```
df$V1[with(rle(diff(as.Date(df$V1)) == 1), {
  inds <- which.max(values & lengths >= 5)
  sum(lengths[1:(inds - 1)]) + 1
})]

#[1] "1979-02-17"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
df=data.frame("V1"=df$V1)
df$V2=difftime(df$V1,c(tail(df$V1,-1),NA))
tmp=rle(as.numeric(df$V2))
df$V3=rep(tmp$lengths,tmp$lengths)

df
           V1        V2 V3
1  1979-01-28  24 hours  2
2  1979-01-29  24 hours  2
3  1979-01-30 336 hours  1
4  1979-02-13  24 hours  1
5  1979-02-14  72 hours  1
6  1979-02-17  24 hours  6
7  1979-02-18  24 hours  6
8  1979-02-19  24 hours  6
9  1979-02-20  24 hours  6
10 1979-02-21  24 hours  6
11 1979-02-22  24 hours  6
12 1979-02-23 288 hours  1
13 1979-03-07 168 hours  1
14 1979-03-14  96 hours  1
15 1979-03-18 264 hours  1
16 1979-03-29  24 hours  3
17 1979-03-30  24 hours  3
18 1979-03-31  24 hours  3
19 1979-04-01  23 hours  1
20 1979-04-02  24 hours  3
21 1979-04-03  24 hours  3
22 1979-04-04  24 hours  3
23 1979-04-05  NA hours  1

df$V1[which.max(df$V3>=5)]
[1] "1979-02-17"
```